# Blank page after save amazon s3 configuration

Tags: 7

I open configuration http://www.mysite.gr/admin/config/media/amazons3 and I put Amazon S3 API Key * Amazon S3 API Secret * and Default Bucket Name * 
When I push the save button I get blank page

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've installed composer and it's working

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your environment enable php "curl" extension.
2. Check your s3-php5-curl library is right place folder
3. check user have Amazon S3 Full Access Permission。